# What is the correct place of Prepare() method? Before defining parameters (with their types and sizes) or after?

Tags: c#, prepared-statement, mysql-connector

I have found two different descriptions of when Prepare() method for prepared SQL statements should be used.

In SqlCommand's documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand_Prepare)

> "Before you call Prepare, specify the data type of each parameter in the statement to be prepared. For each parameter that has a variable length data type, you must set the Size property to the maximum size needed. Prepare returns an error if these conditions are not met."

In MySqlCommand's documentation (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-prepared-preparing.html):

> "After entering your statement, call the Prepare method of the MySqlCommand object. After the statement is prepared, add parameters for each of the dynamic elements in the query."

Are those two documentations excluding each other? Where exactly should Prepare() be used? It seems to be more logical to use Prepare() after defining parameters' data and type.

```
var conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
var cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand();

conn.ConnectionString = strConnection;

conn.Open();
cmd.Connection = conn;

cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO myTable VALUES(NULL, @number, @text)";

cmd.Prepare(); // should it be here?

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", 1);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text", "One");

cmd.Prepare(); // or here?

for (int i=1; i <= 1000; i++)
{
    cmd.Parameters["@number"].Value = i;
    cmd.Parameters["@text"].Value = "A string value";

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Or maybe I should not compare those two documentations and for MySqlCommand use as it according to MySql's dosc and for SqlCommand use it according to Microsoft's docs?

Comment: SqlCommand is for MS Sql Server, not for MySQL, so following that guidance for MySQL is probably not the right thing to do.

Comment: An interesting answer here for Sql Server only though https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/129659/what-is-the-sense-and-benefit-of-using-sqlcommand-prepare

Comment: @Shadow I can agree, but both SqlCommand and MySqlCommand implement IDbCommand interface, so logic of use should (but do not have to) also be same.

Comment: @Steve Thank you for link, I made some tests with firing Prepare() (in both places as in my first post) and without it, it seems to not give me any difference in execution time (20k inserts surrounded by transaction). So I will just abandon Prepare() for now, maybe later I will make some more tests like in your link.